# Взаимодействие двух программ

Tags: java, python, файлы

Есть змейка, написанная на языке [Processing](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing) (по факту, это огромная библиотека для Java). Есть алгоритм, который будет играть в змейку, но написанный на `Python`.

Мне нужно, чтобы программа со змейкой отправляла некоторые данные, а алгоритм их *получал, обрабатывал, и отправлял ответ*: «что делать дальше»

**Как я делал раньше:**
Есть файл: `communication.txt`, в который поочередно пишут обе программы, каждая программа закачивает свою запись *специальным символом*

**Как я делаю это сейчас:**
Есть 2 файла: `snake.txt` и `ai.txt`. Змейка *записывает* информацию в файл `snake.txt`
затем алгоритм ее оттуда достаёт, анализирует, и отправляет ответ в `ai.txt`.
Каждая запись заканчивается *числом*: системное время в миллисекундах (это нужно, чтобы проверять, ответил ли уже собеседник)

В первом случае, в файл в какой-то момент записывали обе программы, что ломало все взаимодействие.

Во втором изредка возникают редкие баги, которую я не могу понять.

**Вопрос:**

Правильно ли вообще использовать *текстовые файлы* для взаимодействия между программами?

Answer (score 1):

То что вы реализуете называется [Inter-process communication (IPC)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Файл - один из способов такого взаимодействия, но есть и другие (сокеты, каналы и т.д.) по ссылке выше есть список.

Что касается конкретно вашей проблемы с файлом:

> В первом случае, в файл в какой-то момент записывали обе программы, что ломало все взаимодействие.

Это называется [состоянием гонки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8). Чтобы решить эту проблему нужно синхронизировать доступ к ресурсу, которым пользуются два или более процесса.
В то время как одна программа открыла файл для записи, другая должна ждать пока первая не закончит запись, и наоборот.

В java nio есть класс [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) который позволяет заблокировать доступ к файлу, он работает на уровне операционной системы, так что пока файл заблокирован вашим Java процессом другие программы не смогут его использовать.
Наверняка в Python есть что то подобное.